# CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 19.10: The CUDA driver initialization failed. (error code = CUDBG_ERROR_UNKNOWN(0x1)

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 19.10

I'm using CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 19.10. All looks good to me after passing some demos in the `NVIDIA_CUDA-10.1_Samples` directory. `nvidia-smi` also works well.

However, when I'm using `cuda-gdb` it says:

```
fatal:  The CUDA driver initialization failed. (error code = CUDBG_ERROR_UNKNOWN(0x1)
```

Maybe I'm missing some libraries here? When I first entered it prompted:

```
cuda-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I installed `libncurses5`.

I installed driver 435 using `ubuntu-drivers` and the CUDA toolkit from a `.run` file. I also switched `gcc` and `g++` from 9 to 8.